# Example for $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\left[ (f(x))^{g(x)} \right]\neq \left(\,\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x)\right)^{\lim_{x\rightarrow a}g(x)}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

I need to prove that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\left[ (f(x))^{g(x)} \right]\neq \left(\,\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x)\right)^{\lim_{x\rightarrow a}g(x)}$$ by giving an example

Here both $f, g$ are real functions and $a\in \Bbb R$

Can you give me an example for $f$ and $g$ ?

thanks!

Comment: Fact is that this is actually true, when it makes sense. Of course, when the limits are in $\{0,\infty,-\infty\}$, only some choices can be determined univocally. However, they are *also* the ones for which there is a natural way to define $\alpha^\beta$.

Comment: Ah, yes, bar perhaps things like $a=0$, $$f(x)=-1\\ g(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{2\left\lfloor \frac1x\right\rfloor+1}&\text{if }x>0\\ 0&\text{if }x\le 0\end{cases}$$ under the assumption that $\alpha^{1/n}$ is defined as $-(-\alpha)^{1/n}$ for all odd integers $n$.